# What is the best way to structure this database?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

So I am in the process of building a database from my clients data. Each month they create roughly 25 csv's, which are unique by their topic and attributes, but they all have 1 thing in common; a registration number.

The registration number is the only common variable across all of these csv's.

My task is to move all of this into a database, for which I am leaning towards postgres (If anyone believes nosql would be best for this then please shout out!).

The big problem; structuring this within a database. Should I create 1 table per month that houses all the data, with column 1 being registration and column 2-200 being the attributes? Or should put all the csv's into postgres as they are, and then join them later?

I'm struggling to get my head around the method to structure this when there will be monthly updates to every registration, and we dont want to destroy historical data - we want to keep it for future benchmarks.

I hope this makes sense - I welcome all suggestions!

Thank you.

Comment: I think making table every month would not be a clean solution , because Creation Date - or Creation moment - is a property and it can declare as a column in your DB . then you can easily filter them by that column and get any query you want

Answer (score 1):

There are some ways where your question is too broad and asking for an opinion (SQL vs NoSQL).

However, the gist of the question is whether you should load your data one month at a time or into a well-developed data model.  Definitely the latter.

My recommendation is the following.

First, design the data model around how the data needs to be stored in the database, rather than how it is being provided.  There may be one table per CSV file.  I would be a bit surprised, though.  Data often wants to be restructured.

Second, design the archive framework for the CSV files. 
 You should archive all the incoming files in a nice directory structure with files from each month.  This structure should be able to accommodate multiple uploads per month, either for all the files or some of them.  Mistakes happen and you want to be sure the input data is available.

Third, copy (this is the Postgres command) the data into staging tables.  This is the beginning of the monthly process.

Fourth, process the data -- including doing validation checks to load it into your data model.

There may be tweaks to this process, based on questions such as:

- Does the data need to be available 24/7 even during the  upload process?
- Does a validation failure in one part of the data prevent uploading any data?
- Are SQL checks (referential integrity and `check`) sufficient for validating the data?
- Do you need to be able to "rollback" the system to any particular update?

These are just questions that can guide your implementation.  They are not intended to be answered here.